# findOneAndUpdate doesn't update object's field (array of objects)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to update multiple fields of a object in an array but it doesn't work.
what am i doing wrong?

**Data Sample:**

```
{
  _id: 'mongodbid',
  name: 'something',
  employees: [
    {
      age: 25,
      name: 'name',
      salary: 500
    },
    {
      age: 28,
      name: 'name2',
      salary: 700
    }
  ],
}
```

**Query:**

```
await this.somethingModel
      .findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          _id: id,
          'employees.age': 25,
        },
        {
          $set: {
            'employees.$.salary': 600,
            'employees.$.name': 'name4',
          }
        },
      )
      .exec();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out problem wasn't with the query itself, rather the schema.
I forgot to add [ ] to the employees field in the schema.

I was using 'raw' from '@nestjs/mongoose' package, I mistakenly wrote this:

```
@Prop(raw({ age: Number, salary: Number, name: String }))
employees: { age: number; salary: number; name: string}[]
```

Instead of this:

```
@Prop(raw([{ age: Number, salary: Number, name: String }]))
employees: { age: number; salary: number; name: string}[]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added a `arrayFilter` in `findOneAndUpdate`. Try with this one, I hope, it works.

```
await this.somethingModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: id,
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "employees.$[elem].salary": 600,
      "employees.$[elem].name": "name4"
    }
  },
  {
    $arrayFilters: [
      {
        "elem.age": 25,
      },
    ],
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but that doesn't work either, I've tried $arrayFilters & arrayFilters, neither works.